# Pass parameter to query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, spring-data-rest

I have run into a problem when passing arguments to this query. When I try to run I get an exception.

```
@Query("select o from Offer o, OfferCriteria ocg where o = ocg.offer and ocg.criteria = 'gender' and ocg.criteriaValue in (2, (select c.gender from Customer as c where c.id = :Id)) ")
    List<Offer> findOffersForCustomer(@Param("Id") String customerId)
```

The exception is

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ParameterTranslationsImpl.getNamedParameterExpectedType(ParameterTranslationsImpl.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.buildParameterMetadata(HQLQueryPlan.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1796)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:342)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:74)
```

It seems it there's a problem when passing parameter Id to the nested query.
I can provide more details if this is scarce.

If I modify the query to

```
select o from Offer o, OfferCriteria ocg where o = ocg.offer and ocg.criteria = 'gender' and ocg.criteriaValue = (select c.gender from Customer as c where c.id = :Id)
```

I get it to run, but no Offers are returned for the customer id provided even though It should.

Comment: Could you please paste the code here where you are setting the parameters.

Comment: Its spring data rest so the param is set just below the @Query annotation, in the method declaration.